# JQuery ajaxSuccess after load - get replaced element?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using `$(elem).load('...')` to refresh a control on my page with new HTML. In `ajaxSuccess` handlers I need to get hold of the `elem` - is this somehow contained in the `ajaxSuccess` parameters? If not, is there a way to pass it through?

Comment: `this` is always `document` in `ajaxSuccess`

Comment: I'd say: not as-is, but there is a way if you use `$.ajax` (which `$(elem).load` is basically just a wrapper around).

Comment: Don't understand the Q. Is [this](https://api.jquery.com/load/#load-url-data-complete) the load method you're talking about?

Comment: @freedomn-m: OK, ... will use $.ajax instead. Unfortunate, because you have to re-implement some logic that jQuery already implements.

Comment: @wazz: Yes it is.

Comment: Yes, re-implement, but when I looked at the $.ajax solution, you can remove quite bit from $.load - eg if you don't use snippets, don't re-implement that part - it was 2 lines, 3 with a `$.fn.` wrapper.